# Kernel python crash when training keras model with GPU

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras

After following the installation guide of the TF doc, I ended up creating a custom dockerfile to install tensorflow with jupyter lab and some custom package and python module for a personnal use.

Steps:

- installation of nvidia driver with run file directly from official nvidia website
- disabling old nouveau driver for previous GPU compatibility
- installating nvidia-container-toolkit
- creating a custom Dockerfile and dockercompose file

I have successfully tested my installation with
`sudo docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi`
which return the nvidia driver version and the cuda version inside the docker.

## My installation of tensorflow with jupyter and some custom modules and packages

### Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu

WORKDIR /tf

# install package for jupyter to file export
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install texlive \
    texlive-latex-extra \
    texlive-xetex \
    texlive-fonts-recommended \
    texlive-plain-generic \
    pandoc -y

# get latest pip version
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# install datascience related python package
RUN pip install ... 

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/jupyter", "lab", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--no-browser", "--allow-root", "--notebook-dir=/tf/"]
```

### docker compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  jupyter:
    build: .
    image: jupyter_tf_gpu_custom:latest
    container_name: jupyter-tf-gpu
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      . . . traefik related labels
    volumes:
      - jupyter_data:/tf/
    networks:
      - traefik-network
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
          - driver: nvidia
            count: all
            capabilities: [gpu]

networks:
  traefik-network:
    external: true

volumes:
  jupyter_data:
```

### tf version

Version: 2.13.1

### Server specs

- OS: Debian (bullseye)
- Quadro RTX 4000
- 32Gb RAM
- 6C/12T Xeon CPU
- nvidia driver: 535.129.03 (Cuda version: 12.2)

## Problem details

Inside the docker from jupyter lab interface, the `nvidia-smi` command work well and show the GPU with the driver version and the CUDA version.
When training a Sequential model (no matter the size, any model) the kernel crash on the `fit()` method. The same code work well when using the CPU.

### Additionnal warnings messages from TF when running code:

1. **successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero**
2. 

## Tested solutions

1. Better handling the memory:

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

2. Installation of tensorflow[and-cuda] because I had this warning message:
   **Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered**
3. Try different nvidia driver version, 530, 470, 370

Comment: After some additionnal research, I used a workaround which is using NGC:
[https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tensorflow](https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tensorflow)

Make sure to select an image version compatible with your current nvidia driver version.

In my case I used the image `nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:23.10-tf2-py3` and kept the Dockerfile globaly identical.